# Function only outputs one string

Tags: javascript

Beginner here: This function give me only the first longest string. How to make it to output all largest strings with the same length?

```
var words = ["one", "two", "tree", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"];

function LongestWords(array){

var longWord = array[0];

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i].length > longWord.length){
            longWord = array[i];
        }
    }
    return longWord;
}

console.log(LongestWords(words));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Find the length of the longest string

Step 2: Filter the strings that has the length same as the longest string.

```js
let words = ["one", "two", "tree", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"];

let longest = words.sort(function (a, b) { return b.length - a.length; })[0].length;

let allongString = words.filter(function(string){ return string.length === longest})

console.log(allongString)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but this is advanced level for me :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `push` to add new element on a array.

```js
var words = ["one", "two", "tree", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"];

function LongestWords(array){
    var longWord = [];
    var longWordLen = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (array[i].length > longWordLen){
          //If the current word is longer, reset the longWord and push the current word
          longWord = [];
          longWord.push( array[i] );
          longWordLen = array[i].length;
        } else if( array[i].length == longWordLen) {
          //If the current word is the same length, just push the current word
          longWord.push( array[i] );
        }
    }
    return longWord;
}

console.log(LongestWords(words));
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried with a new array, but I didn't know how to make it work. Your explanation is great!

Comment: @dtsc, You can update your question with the new array if you are having some problem. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need a single loop for getting the longest words. This approach has a iteration count of **O(n)**.

Sorting, as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48357389/1447675) has in the best cas a complexity of **O(nlogn)** followed by a sinlge iteration of **O(n)**.

```js
var words = ["one", "two", "tree", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"],
    result = words.reduce(function (r, w, i) {
        if (!i || r[0].length < w.length) {
            return [w];
        }
        if (r[0].length === w.length) {
            r.push(w);
        }
        return r;
    }, undefined);
    
console.log(result);
```